# I have a error on my android studio

Tags: android

[image]

Execution failed for task 'app:processDebugResources', Error: more than one library with package name android.support.graphics.drawable"

Comment: Please post your gradle files (not Screenshots, but code)

Answer (score 0):

First we can't see nothing on your picture.

Second i think the error is clear.

You have to library that contains a package name android.support.graphics.drawable and android Studio can't decide witch one do you need.

So try to look at all you library and search for the 2 that contains android.support.graphics.drawable and delete one of the 2.

Regards.